# Create user generated text for website

Tags: javascript, html, database

I have created this "for fun" website:
http://designduck.dk/lol_mul/hvadsiger/

It is set up with a simple javascript that uses a  var to get the text.

I just want the users to be able to add in their own sentences. How do I do that?

Like with a textbox where they write their sentence and then it gets sent to a database and gets implemented to the  var

I know it should probably be set up with some sort of database, but how? 
Can't find any guides on the interwebs :-/

Comment: Search for a tutorial about mysql and php. There are plenty of tutorials out there on how to store values in a database table.

Comment: and be aware of sql injection ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To translate Smuuf's answer into code:

Instead of

```
<div id="text">Det er satme smukt!</div>
```

You could do

```
<?php
    // Default text
    $text = 'Hello!';

    // When alternative text is given
    if(isset($_GET['text']) && !empty($_GET['text'])){

        // htmlspecialchars to sanitze the database and prevent XSS hacks
        $text = htmlspecialchars($_GET['text']); 
    }
?>
```

```
<div id="text"><?php echo $text; ?></div>
```

Comment: I meant it as pure JS solution, but who cares. :D .. PHP is much simpler ;P

Comment: Uhoh, js only? My bad, one sec.

Comment: Woops, artistandsocial was faster!

Answer (score 1):

Why database? You could just get GET parameters from URL, like: `http://designduck.dk/lol_mul/hvadsige/?fun=Hahahahahah`

.. sanitize it, and then paste it into that funny box. All that could be done with JavaScript.

And the user input could be provided via some `<form>` and `<input>` at the bottom of the page, sending GET request at itself.

Answer (score 1):

As Smuff already explained, you can create a deep link for the website.
A deep link is your URL with an appended GET parameter, like http://designduck.dk/lol_mul/hvadsiger/?text=myowntext .

You can query for this parameter with JavaScript that way:

```
var paramArray = window.location.search.substr(1).split("&"); // fetch all GET params
var parameters = {};
var text;

// save all params in object
for ( var i = 0; i < paramArray.length; i++) {
    var tmp = paramArray[i].split("=");
    parameters[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
}


// insert the text parameter into an element
document.querySelector('.your-element').innerText = parameters['text'];
```

That's how you insert the text into your box.

**To create a deep link** just add a new button *create deep link* to this site, fetch the text from the textbox and change your `window.location.href` accordingly.